# How to trigger jQuery event only when BODY Element is clicked not the internal elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<div class="lamp_color_div"></div>
<br>
<div class="lamp_colorpicker_div"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$("body").click(function(){
    console.log("SLIDE UPPPPPPPPPPPPP!");
    $(this).append("SLIDE UPPPPPPPPPPPPP!");
    $(".lamp_color_div").slideUp();
    $(".lamp_colorpicker_div").slideUp();
});
```

CSS

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

JsFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/DynamicRemo/qfu2vwj2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `target`.

Like this:

```
$("body").click(function () {

    if (event.target == document.body) {
        $(".lamp_color_div").slideUp();
        $(".lamp_colorpicker_div").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, and what if there`s a Container Div instead of Body Tag?
 Can you help for this also...

Comment: I found the Answer my self, just with simple alterations.

`$("html, body")` and `if ( (event.target == document.body) || $(event.target).hasClass('container_class_name')`.